# How to accèss query string in function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following shortcode in Wordpress:

```
function customquery() {
  query_posts('cat=18&tag=mytag');
}
add_shortcode('query', 'customquery');
```

The above works fine.  I need "tag" to accept a parameter from the URL query string.  I've tried this:

```
query_posts('cat=18&tag='.$_GET["tag"].'''');
```

That breaks the page.  Since this is shortcode, I'm not sure if something needs to be passed as a function argument.  However, I don't see that .$_GET["tag"] can be executed as an argument.  How else can I do this?

Comment: You are getting a syntax error from the `''''` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$my_tag = '';

if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
  $my_tag = urlencode($_GET["tag"]);
}

$query_str = "cat=18&tag=" . $my_tag;

query_posts($query_str);
```

Comment: That broke the page.  I tried echo $query_str right after the assignment but still nothing.

Comment: sorry. i missed a ) . pls try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query_posts('cat=18&tag='.urlencode($_GET["tag"]));
```